# Using a Kendo UI Project Template in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-asp.net-mvc

After installing the latest Telerik UI for ASP.NET MVC, and choosing File - New Project - Templates - Telerik - Web,  should I see a Kendo UI template project?  (I am watching the Telerik "The Basics of UI for ASP.NET MVC" video and it shows one there). I am using VS 2013 and Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

I received a reply from Telerik Tech. Support in one of their forums.  It appears that the project templates just have been renamed to new names.  I chose "Telerik VB MVC Web Application" instead of "VB Kendo UI for MVC Web Application" (the project template name used in the video) and all of the functionality from the video appears to be there (copying the Kendo UI files into the project, adding CSS and JS lines into the Layout file, giving Kendo UI intellisense, etc.).